# How to make recessed button in CSS

Tags: css

In the image below, the top image is what I currently have on a site, it uses an actual Image.

What I want to do is make something more like the bottom image using pure CSS, I cannot figure out how to do it though, can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: `box-shadow` and `linear-gradient`s as backgrounds, I suppose. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Are you creating the gray boxes with an image? Just changing the background color and using a box shadow - I'm not sure what you want to do specifically.

Comment: Are you trying to create the shadow effect or change the picture?

Comment: The actual image inside of the button does not matter, I just need to get the actual button to look similar to the bottom image.  The top image is made completely with an Image and the bttom I would like to replicate with CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS3 has a lot of solutions.  Try this:

```
div.exampleboxshadowj {
background-color: #EEE;
float: left;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: 40px;
height: 65px;
width: 160px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset -5px -5px 5px 5px#888;
box-shadow: inset -5px -5px 5px 5px #888;
}
```

Though you can change the color to blue, if you want.

[Here](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) is a great link for all the info you could want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you properly, you are trying to change the image when it is clicked or is active. If so, for that you can use `:focus` or `:active` to generate such effect.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/X26sy/) with background color instead of a picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this link to get the gradient effect on those buttons (I haven't tested it myself)

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient

I'd imagine that since they use the `background` property, you would need to have the actual images on the buttons inside some sort of position container.

It would be easier and possible more cross-browser friendly to simply create the images in a sprite map and switch the background-position when they are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use this css3 browsers compatible css  code for your requirement :-

```
    .shadow {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-color: rgb(55,79,99); /* Needed for IEs */
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 13px 0px 19px 5px rgba(38,56,70,0.9);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 13px 0px 19px 5px rgba(38,56,70,0.9);
    box-shadow: inset 13px 0px 19px 5px rgba(38,56,70,0.9);

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";
    zoom: 1;
}
```

**or see the live demo** :- http://jsfiddle.net/dte78/32/

[and can read more about box shadow](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/)